# Disable buttons within one of many forms using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of forms like this:

```
<form class="some-name">
    <input type="hidden" name="bill" value"flower" />
    <button value="0">Yes</button>
    <button value="1">No</button>
    <button value="2">No</button>
</form>

<form class="some-name">
    <input type="hidden" name="ben" value"men" />
    <button value="0">Yes</button>
    <button value="1">No</button>
    <button value="2">No</button>
</form>
```

**What I want to happen**

When a user clicks a button, I want to disable the other buttons within that form.

Currently I'm trying with this jQuery, but it's not working?

My thinking behind it is the current element is a button so you want it's parent which is the form and then all the buttons in the form?

```
$(document).on("click", ".some-name button", function(){
    $($(this)).parent().$("button").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

also tried:

```
$(document).on("click", ".some-name button", function(){
    $($(this)).parent("button").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

but no luck with either?

Comment: why have you got `$($(this))` ???

Comment: @ChristopherKenney got the brackets muddled up when editing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".some-name button", function(){
    $(this) // currently clicked button
      .siblings("button")  // all neighbor of clicked button
      .prop("disabled", true);  // set disabled
});
```

**Related refs:**

- **[`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)**
- **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$($(this)).parent().$("button")
```

That's not valid jQuery.  You want something like:

```
$(this).parent().find('button')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".some-name button", function(){
     $(this).parent('form').children("button").attr("disabled", true);
});​
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkgge/)